# Start range from 1 onward

Tags: shell-script, array, for

I am counting multiple log files with the range starting from 1 onward however it's starting from 0.

```
path=(/home/folder/text/*)

for 1 int ${!path}; do

         printf "$s: $s\n" $i "${list[i]##*/}";

done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shell code makes little sense as it uses the wrong syntax for the `for` loop and in the substitution to get the indexes, and also does not use `printf` format strings correctly.

I'm guessing that you'd want to do something like this:

```
i=0
for pathname in /home/folder/text/*; do
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$i" "$( basename "$pathname" )"
done
```

This would enumerate the names found under `/home/folder/text` (excluding hidden names).

You can replace `"$( basename "$pathname" )"` in the above with `"${pathname##*/}"` if you wish.

Using an array as you show in your own code:

```
pathnames=( /home/folder/text/* )

i=0
for pathname in "${pathnames[@]}"; do
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$i" "$( basename "$pathname" )"
done
```

Would you want to iterate over the indexes of the array:

```
pathnames=( /home/folder/text/* )

for index in "${!pathnames[@]}"; do
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$index" "$( basename "${pathnames[$index]}" )"
done
```

Note that `bash` arrays start on index zero.  Adding 1 to each index:

```
pathnames=( /home/folder/text/* )

for index in "${!pathnames[@]}"; do
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$(( index + 1 ))" "$( basename "${pathnames[$index]}" )"
done
```